# DoCmd.ApplyFilter Syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter

I'm having a little trouble applying a filter that refers to multiple text boxes in a form for the Where Condition.

I have a button called Search_All, and am trying to set up the first two text boxes:

```
Private Sub Search_All_Click()
       DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[ESN] like '*' & [Forms]![Search]![ESN TEXT]  & '*' Or [CommentsField] like '*' & [Forms]![Search]![COMMENTS TEXT] & '*'"
End Sub
```

I can enter a value for ESN and filter successfully, but when I enter something into the COMMENTS TEXT it filters everything out and doesn't display any records.

Comment: Does comments contain a single quote like in *can't*, *it's*, *I'm*?

Comment: @Parfait actually, since the parameters are concatenated by the database engine, and not by VBA, that shouldn't be a problem. Not a clue what is, though

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning up the quotes:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[ESN] Like '*" & [Forms]![Search]![ESN TEXT]  & "*' Or [CommentsField] Like '*" & [Forms]![Search]![COMMENTS TEXT] & "*'"
```